# Cocoa screensaver preview

Tags: cocoa, opengl, preview, screensaver

I have some kind of a problem with the screensaver preview. This is a simple OpenGL screensaver clearing BG to certain color (purple on image). It must color fill fullscreen, and it does in test-run, but on preview I see only this:

[image: Preview box]

some code:

```
- (void)initOpengl {
    [[openglView openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 0.5f);

    glClearDepth(1.0f); 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}

- (void)resize:(NSSize)newSize {
    [openglView setFrameSize:newSize];

    [[openglView openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];

    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)newSize.width, (GLsizei)newSize.height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(30.0f, (GLfloat)newSize.width / (GLfloat)newSize.height, 
                   0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    [[openglView openGLContext] update];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize {
    [super setFrameSize:newSize];
    [self resize:newSize];
}
- (void)setFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    [super setFrame:frameRect];
    [self resize:frameRect.size];
}
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [[openglView openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFlush();
}

- (void)animateOneFrame {
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. How we can help You without seeing code?

Comment: I though someone already had this issue and we can solve it without digging in the code =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very stupid mistake, issue solved. 
Instead of
    [openglView setFrameSize:newSize]; 
I should've used 
    [openglView setFrame:...]; 
with the proper arguments